# 403 Current user cannot create courses [forbidden] while creating a course for Google classroom api (.Net)

Tags: google-classroom

I have created a VisualStudio (C#) project, wihch use google classroom apis.
With Super admin, It can create a course, but with delegated admin, It returns an error.
I have use a delegated admin. Why does that error return ?

Errors [
Message[@UserCannotCreateCourse Current user cannot create courses.] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]
]

my code is below given

```
string[] Scopes = {ClassroomService.Scope.ClassroomCourses};

UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    string credPath = "token.json";
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        Scopes,
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
}

var service = new ClassroomService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Classroom test"
});

var body = new Course()
{
    Name = "MyFirstClass",
    OwnerId = "me"
};
var course = service.Courses.Create(body).Execute();
```

"credentials.json"File is from My Google Cloud Platform project.
My project is verificated.
./auth/classroom/courses
./auth/classroom/rosters
(etc.)

Delegated admin is created by Google Console.
I added custom admin role.

Comment: How did you perform the domain wide delegation? Can you give us more insight into this?

Comment: I created a project in Google Cloud Platform, and verificated my application.
This error happend when I changed the google account (from Super Admin to delegated Admin) for Authentication.

Comment: Did you update the credentials in the code after performing the domain wide delegation? What exactly do you mean by "This error happend when I changed the google account for Authentication"? Where in the code are you performing the authentication for the service account?

Comment: if domain wide delegation means 
an autorization by by  google console (Security - API controls), I did that.
This error happend when I signin with Google workspace for Education account.
And today I found classroom api success to create a course with Google workspace account (not for Education).

Answer (score 0):

I found that the owner of the classroom course must a member of classroom_teachers Group. (If the account is not the super admin)

With an account that has not be a teacher, classroom api gets error.
And after becoming a teacher (manually sign-in, and create a classroom course), classroom api succeeded.

So, before creating a course, I join that account into classroom_teacher group.

Thank you.

Comment: this works, this happens when groups for business is  activated, weird thing is that I have another account where the account is not in the group and works perfectly.